# Customizable variable with predefined alist keys

Tags: customize, customization

I'd like to create a customizable variable `foo-paths` with certain options.

```el
(defcustom foo-paths nil
  "Paths for foo-related things."
  :group 'foo
  :options '(foo-1 foo-2)
  :type '(alist :key-type symbol :value-type (file :must-match t)))
```

I'd like for the user to *only* be able to provide values for the specified keys in `:options`, not to add new options.

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html#Composite-Types) doesn't offer a way to do this--the user can add new elements to the alist through the Customize interface.

Is there a way to achieve this? The functionality may not be impacted by the addition of new alist elements, but it seems strange that there's no way to specify a variable that has certain options and *only* those options.

Comment: An alist is extensible, by definition. See custom type `list`, which specifies a list of a prescribed length and element types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a partial answer.  The `:must-match` requirement seems broken (a bug?).

An alist is extensible by definition.  And `:options` does not enforce using its values.

Custom type `list` specifies a list of prescribed length and element types. Use `repeat` of `list`.  In other words,`repeat` lists of two elements of given types.  For your permissible keys, use `choice` with `const`.

```el
(defcustom foo-paths nil
  "Paths for foo-related things."
  :group 'foo
  :type '(repeat (list (choice (const foo-1) (const foo-2))
                       (file :must-match t))))
```

You can also do something like this:

```el
(defcustom foo-paths nil
  "Paths for foo-related things."
  :group 'foo
  :options '(foo-1 foo-2)
  :type '(alist
          :key-type (choice (const foo-1) (const foo-2))
          :value-type (file :must-match t)))
```

(Based on your comments, it's not very clear what you really want.)

Comment: TBH, this is not as good as the alist type. With the alist, the keys specified in `:options` are shown be default; here, they are not. Also, the user is still able to add extraneous elements with `INS` in the Customize interface.

Comment: `'(list (cons (const :tag "Foo-1 path" foo-1)
             (file :must-match t))
       (cons (const :tag "Foo-2 path" foo-2)
             (file :must-match t)))` comes close, but I need to provide an initial value that fits, so it needs to be something like: `((foo-1 . "") (foo-2 . ""))`. Also, the Customize interface will say `Cons-cell` in for each list element.

Comment: Too bad. You can use `alist` or you can use `repeat` or you can use `restricted-sexp`. There are multiple possibilities. That just-what-you-want is not offered out of the box is unfortunate. File an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: `repeat` means you can add more elements (it is a list). But `list` specifies that each element is locked into only N elements of the specified types. The `INS` you are referring to is just about adding more elements to the overall value (a list).

Comment: If you want each list element to be a dotted pair then use `cons` instead of `list`. Same idea: you specify the types of the elements of the pair. The point is that both of these satisfy your requirement of not letting the user "*add new options*". The `alist` type, which you now say is "*better*", does not satisfy your own requirement. You need to decide what your question really is.

Comment: The most flexible customization type is `restricted-sexp`. It takes some getting used to, and it can be cumbersome, but you can do pretty much anything you want with it.

Comment: I think an alist is fine; as mentioned, it doesn't impact functionality, and is the closest to what I want "out of the box".